# Повтор знака после закрывающей скобки

Tags: пунктуация, скобки

Как известно, знак после закрывающих кавычек не повторяется. А что насчёт закрывающей скобки? Я нигде не нашёл соответствующего правила.

> Я так долго бежал (знала бы ты, как устал!)!

(Понятно, что в живом тексте было бы стилистически вернее просто не вкладывать предложение в скобках внутрь другого: *"Я так долго бежал! (Знала бы, как устал!)"*, но мой вариант — просто иллюстрация вопроса.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вставка, заключенная в скобки, при ее изъятии не должна влиять на пунктуацию предложения.

[**О сочетаниях знаков препинания**](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/165-oszp) (Грамота.ру)

> **§ 203.** После закрывающей скобки, которой заканчивается предложение, ставится знак препинания, требуемый предложением в целом, независимо от того, какой знак может стоять перед закрывающей скобкой...

P. S. На мой взгляд, такая запись, как у Вас в примере, графически не очень красива, что ли. Я бы оформил так: ***Я так долго бежал! (Знала бы ты, как устал!)***

О! Пока писал ответ, Вы добавили такой же вариант!